# How to switch between SSH keys with the ruby-git gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, ruby-git

Is there any way to set different SSH keys to [ruby-git](https://github.com/ruby-git/ruby-git) gem configuration on the fly, so I can work with different private repos?

What I've done is working well, but it works with one SSH key only.

I have created `/ruby_git.sh` in the root folder of my Rails app:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ./certs/private_key "$@"
```

I have created `/certs/private_key` with my SSH key:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I have created `/initializers/git_init.rb`:

```rb
Git.configure do |config|
  config.git_ssh = Rails.root.join("ruby_git.sh").to_s
end
```

I have also tried another approach, to create custom sh scripts and SSH private key files for each repo in runtime and delete them after use. But this seems to alter `Git` globally, so the next thread/session inherits the new `Git` config:

```rb
# @repo_id, @ssh_url and @private_key are instance variables set
# based on the repo that we try to interact with

cert_path   = Rails.root.join("git_config", "certs", @repo_id).to_s
config_path = Rails.root.join("git_config", "configs", "#{@repo_id}.sh").to_s
git_config  = "#!\/bin\/bash\n\nexec \/usr\/bin\/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i #{cert_path} \"$@\""

File.open(config_path, "w") { |f|
  f.write(git_config)
}

File.open(cert_path, "w") { |f|
  f.write(@private_key)
}

File.chmod(0755, config_path)
File.chmod(0600, cert_path)

Git.init

Git.configure { |config|
  config.git_ssh = config_path
}

Git.ls_remote(@ssh_url)

FileUtils.remove_entry(cert_path)
FileUtils.remove_entry(config_path)
```

I tried to work with `~/.ssh/config`. The following is working, but it does not mach my needs.

```
Host github.com
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile /home/ubuntu/.ssh/repo_1_private_key
```

I'm working with multiple repos. SSH pair created for each of them. Public part used as a deploy key. No users.

I need to measure one repo/key pair from another and do not let ssh have access to other keys or iterate through them.

something like

```
Host github.com/organization_1/repo_1
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile /home/ubuntu/.ssh/repo_1_private_key

Host github.com/organization_2/repo_2
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile /home/ubuntu/.ssh/repo_2_private_key
```

is not working because `github.com/organization/repo` doesn't mach with `github.com` host and configuration is skipped when tried to `git clone git@github.com:organization/repo.git`.

Comment: I think you will have to to add ```Host org1.github.com
  Hostname github.com
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile /home/ubuntu/.ssh/repo_1_private_key
``` and then `git clone git@org1.github.com:organization/repo.git`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried placing the ssh config file and specify which host to connect?.

I have not dealt with ruby scripts. I have dealt with ssh enough to deal with such things. There is a ssh configuration file that helps me out in such usecases. It is the `~/.ssh/config`

In your usecase, can you please try to have some setup like below line,

```
Host myfriendlyhostname1
     HostName git.example.com
     User user1
     Port 1234
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa1

Host myfriendlyhostname2
     HostName git.example.com
     User user2
     Port 1234
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa2
```

What this does is,
If you place the above inside your `~/.ssh/config` file, this maps the name of the config to pick the connection

> In your case, I assume you have same host different credentials right?

If you `ssh myfriendlyhostname1`, it will connect using the identity provided for `user1` to `git.example.com`.

If you `ssh myfriendlyhostname2`, it will connect using the identity provided for `user2` to `git.example.com`.

When searched, I found this link that has more examples, https://linuxize.com/post/using-the-ssh-config-file/

What I have not tried is `git clone` using `myfriendlyhostname1`
If you tried it let me know how that went.

Comment: Hi @reflexdemon check out the edits I have made to the question, that tries solving it like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can say, however ruby sets up to say, `git -c core.sshcommand='/usr/bin/ssh -F my.temp.config'` and set up your one-shot connection-setup params in that temp config.

Comment: Thanks @jthill, but could you provide more informations? An example of the shell script and how to invoke it from Ruby. Having a single tmp configuration would not be thread-safe, because multiple threads could attempt to write and read from it.

Comment: I don't know ruby, in shell scripts you just say `mktemp` and you get a unique tempfile, there's options for where. Ruby has to have an equivalent; and I'd think its git bindings let you supply options on the git command, no?